# (80's-90's) Spaceship heading for earth with pods containg a small robot that can build a cyborg/robot from the surrounding enviroment

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, cyborg

A film (rented VHS I think) from the late 80' or early 90's, some kind of pods found their way (don't remember how) into an spaceship heading for earth. These pods were egg/walnut shaped and orange/brown and approximately the size of a basketball. In these pods there was a small machine with tools that could use material from surrounding environment to build some kind of robot/cyborg. I remember that it used a human body as a base to build this robot/cyborg. Some people were trying to stop this ship from reaching earth but in the end it crashed and then you saw at least one surviving pod. 
I think Martin Landau was in the film but I may be mixing things up.

Comment: see OP comment below confirming duplicate

Answer (score 9):

This is [*Moontrap*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moontrap) with Walter Koenig and Bruce Campbell. Direct release to VHS, unavailable on DVD or Bluray.

Comment: Thanks a lot, trying to remember the title of the film almost drove me crazy. I mixed up the the film with "The dark side of the moon" wich is utter s**t I found out after 2 minutes. I saw that somebody is selling the DVD on ebay and Amazon. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: The DVD is a bootleg. Trust me, I've looked. And please accept my answer if you feel it's correct, just click the checkmark next to it.